# jms:listener for OracleAQ

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, oracle-aq

Concerning the following configuration for OracleAQ in Spring

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    client-id="LUKAS34"
    message-converter="messageConverter"
    container-class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer"
    destination-type="topic">
    <jms:listener destination="AQ_TS_MY_TEST"  
        ref="messageDelegate" method="handleMessage" subscription="LUKAS34" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

The problem here is that despite the fact that we don't have subscription LUKAS34 (but we have other - LUKAS) above configuration causes that all messages from AQ_TS_MY_TEST are read.

I expect that if I define `subscription="LUKAS"` all messages for this subscription will be read and otherwise none will be read.

What is the problem with above configuration?

Additionally I see that that in table:

```
select *
from ALL_QUEUE_SUBSCRIBERS;
```

is many entries like 'TSUB_1_*' which seems to me that spring configuration 'creates' new consumers and name 'LUKAS' in configuration is skipped.

Ok... I modified (it's not a solution but it shows where the problem is...) some spring class. Let's take a look at private method ... org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer#initResourcesIfNecessary

```
private void initResourcesIfNecessary() throws JMSException {
        if (getCacheLevel() <= CACHE_CONNECTION) {
            updateRecoveryMarker();
        }
        else {
            if (this.session == null && getCacheLevel() >= CACHE_SESSION) {
                updateRecoveryMarker();
                this.session = createSession(getSharedConnection());
            }
            if (this.consumer == null && getCacheLevel() >= CACHE_CONSUMER) {
                this.consumer = createListenerConsumer(this.session);
                synchronized (lifecycleMonitor) {
                    registeredWithDestination++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

if I change here (in this method consumer name from randomly generated (as I suppose randomly generated by spring) to my fixed name 'LUKAS' everything works as I expected - my listener reads only those messages which are defined in PL/SQL side for consumer 'LUKAS'.

So the question is if I can somehow set up in spring jms:listener configuration consumer name?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your

```
destination-type="topic"
```

to:

```
destination-type="durableTopic"
```

And seeing if that works.